# How to mock an inner function in Sinon?

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, sinon

Suppose I have two functions, `foo` is called inside a `bar`. I have a Meteor app, so I decided to use meteor `mocha` package along with `sinon` and `chai` and not `jest`

```
// foo.js

const foo = () => // call to a google maps api;
export default foo;


// bar.js

const bar = (x) => {
  foo();
  ...
};
export default bar;
```

What is the correct approach of mocking `foo` in this case

Currently I've came up with the following solution:

```
import foo from 'path/to/foo.js'
import bar from 'path/to/bar.js'

describe('my test suite', function() {
  it('should pass the test', function() {
    foo = spy();
    bar(5);
    assert(foo.calledOnce);
  });
});
```

The following code works, but is that correct to redefine `foo`?

**UPDATE**

Also, it's not possible to create a mock or stub this way, which makes me think that Sinon is not suitable for mocking standalone functions

Answer (score 6):

`Sinon` works well on standalone JavaScript functions.

Here is an example of how to wrap the default export of a module in a `Sinon` spy:

```js
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import * as fooModule from 'path/to/foo.js'
import bar from 'path/to/bar.js'

describe('my test suite', function() {
  it('should pass the test', function() {
    const spy = sinon.spy(fooModule, 'default');  // wrap the function in a spy
    bar(5);
    assert(spy.calledOnce);  // SUCCESS
    spy.restore();  // restore the original function
  });
});
```

Here is an example of how to replace the default export of a module with a `Sinon` stub:

```js
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import * as fooModule from 'path/to/foo.js'
import bar from 'path/to/bar.js'

describe('my test suite', function() {
  it('should pass the test', function() {
    const stub = sinon.stub(fooModule, 'default').returns('something else');  // stub the function
    bar(5);  // foo() returns 'something else' within bar(5)
    assert(stub.calledOnce);  // SUCCESS
    stub.restore();  // restore the original function
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, stubbing this way works, however for some reason I get false when calling calledOnce on a stub

Comment: Does it pass if you change the line to `assert(stub.called);`?  (is the stub getting called more than once?)

Comment: No, also returns false

Comment: Did you put the `spy` and `stub` tests in the same file?  If a function has already been wrapped in a spy/stub/mock/fake during a given test it can't be wrapped again until it has been restored.  I updated my answer above to call `restore` to avoid that particular error.

Comment: No, I'm using only 1 stub in the test. When logging the stub in the console I've noticed that it has `notCalled:true` which is weird

Comment: Seems like the possible cause is documented here: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1545